# Grok the pre- and postincrement

Tags: javascript

Here is the example code:

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
    console.log(i);
}

var x = 20;
switch(x++){
  case 20:
    console.log("20 " + x++);
    break;
  case 21:
    console.log("21 " + x++);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(x++);
    break;
}
```

In case of postincrement both console.log(*expression*) and switch(*expression*){} get the value before being incremented. 
In my example I get "20 21" as the result of the switch statement.

Why in for loop it doesn't really metter if I put post- or preincrement ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand whats happening, you can rewrite the for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

to a while loop like

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

Imagening it as a while loop might make it clearer, why it does not matter if you write `i++` or `++i`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the statement that does the increment:

```
i++
```

Nothing is done with the return value. It isn't assigned to a variable. It isn't passed to a function.

It doesn't matter if the return value is taken before or after the increment because it is ignored.